# Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy- unable to resolve this issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, gradle, crashlytics-android

I am trying to implement crashlitics in my android app but the problem is whenever i am running the app i am getting above error .kindly help me to get it resolved .

i also added multidex enabled true and i am using following below dependencies .

plz let me know the issue .

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.johnkil.android-robototextview:robototextview:4.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'

// Check for v11.4.2 or higher
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.1.0'

// (Recommended) Add Analytics
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.1.0'

// Add dependency
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
```

Comment: You are using [firebase libraries](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_june_17_2019) which require androidx libraries. You are using support and androidx both, and you can't do it. You have to migrate to androidx.

Comment: how do i migrate to android x - i tried to click on refactor and than migrate . but didnt work.